# How to use file.php?swf=

Tags: php

So i'm basically trying to make something like this:

http://mywebsite.nl/file.php?swf=Frontier_Psychiatrist.swf

I have a folder where I store all the .swf files, but now I need to know how I use the file.php**?swf=** 
I'm looking to find some tutorials how I use that last part that I just mentioned, problem is I don't know what it's called.

I really don't know how to explain it any better, I hope anyone knows what I mean!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called GET parameters. You can access it like this:

```
$_GET['swf'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: English version of the manual link ;) -http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract it from the URL you can use this:-

```
$filename = $_GET['swf'];
echo $filename;
```

If you want to extract it from a string you can use regex.